# JavaScript: Return result from recursion

Tags: javascript, function, recursion

I wrote the following function to traverse a JSON-structured data to locate the value of the provided `targetField` and the paths `pathArr`, but I am struggling with returning result from the recursion, because the value for the targetField may not exist.

This function uses a global variable named **result** for returning the targetField's value, but this can get carried over to the next call of findValue(), which may not find the value but shows the last call's `result`. So I am wondering what's the best way of solving this problem without using the global variable `result`.

If the call of findValue() does not find the targetField's value, just return **null as the result**.

The **pathArr** is something like `["first_level", "second_level", "third_level"];`

```
var result = null;
function findValue(jsonData, pathArr, targetField) {

if (pathArr.length == 0) {
    result = targetField in jsonData ? jsonData[targetField] : result;
    return result;
} else {

    var curNode = pathArr.shift();

    if (curNode in jsonData) {
        jsonData = jsonData[curNode];
    }

    if (Array.isArray(jsonData)) {
        jsonData.forEach(function(thisData) {
            findValue(thisData, pathArr, targetField);
        });
    } else {
        findValue(jsonData, pathArr, targetField);
    }
}   

return result;
}
```

**Edit:**
Thanks to everyone who replied.

Using unobf's improved code, I used this testData to do a testing, but it seems only returning the last match:

```
var testData = {
"num_found" : 3,
"category" : "social",

"groups": [ 
{"group" : {
    "source" : [{"id" : "testID1", "num": 10, "field": "sociaology", "sub-subject" : "socialeconomy"}, 
                {"id" : "testID2", "num": 20, "field": "mathematics", "sub-subject": ""}, 
                {"id" : "testID3", "num": 7, "field": "biology", "sub-subject" : ""}
                ],
    "identifier" : "shelf-01-E-XW1"
}},
{"group" : {
    "source" : [{"id" : "testID4", "num": 50, "field": "sociaology2", "sub-subject" : ""}, 
                {"id" : "testID5", "num": 44, "field": "mathematics2", "sub-subject": ""}, 
                {"id" : "testID6", "num": 75, "field": "biology2", "sub-subject" : "european studies2"}
                ],
    "identifier" : "shelf-02-W-EW3"
}},

{"group" : {
    "source" : [{"id" : "testID7", "num": 59, "field": "sociaology3", "sub-subject" : "socialeconomy3"}, 
                {"id" : "testID8", "num": 47, "field": "mathematics3", "sub-subject": ""}, 
                {"id" : "testID9", "num": 76, "field": "biology3", "sub-subject" : "european studies3"}
                ],
    "identifier" : "shelf-03-W-GW5"
}}
]
};
```

and I found I had to change this line of code

```
return {value : result};
```

to

```
return result;
```

**Test:**

```
for (var i = 0; i < testData.groups.length; i++) {
    var value = findValue(testData.groups[i], ["group", "source"], "sub-subject");
    console.log("found value: " + value);
}
```

Comment: Look up breadth-first search (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Breadth-first_search), and depth-first search (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Depth-first_search), there's algorithms available that explains how to code this..

Comment: Why are you calling `findValue` recursively without returning its return value, instead relying on that call setting a global variable (`result`)?

Comment: I consider the global variable result a temporary solution. I first tried to narrow the scope of the variable result inside the function, but it didn't work, but let me try it again.

Answer (score 1):

Fundamentally, all of the paths through your function must return a value. Currently, there's a path that doesn't, the path that takes the `forEach`:

```
jsonData.forEach(function(thisData) {
    findValue(thisData, pathArr, targetField);
});
```

There, you probably want `some` (so you can stop when you find it) and a variable that you can set to the found value, e.g:

```
var retval;
```

and

```
jsonData.some(function(thisData) {
    retVal = findValue(thisData, pathArr, targetField);
    return !!retVal; // Stops the `some` loop, doesn't exit `findValue`
});
if (retVal) {
    return retVal;
}
```

---

Side note: You don't want to declare `result` outside the function, there's no need. The function can be entirely self-contained. Here's a version that is self-contained, for instance:

```
function findValue(jsonData, pathArr, targetField) {
    var result = null;

    if (pathArr.length == 0) {
        result = targetField in jsonData ? jsonData[targetField] : null;
    } else {

        var curNode = pathArr.shift();

        if (curNode in jsonData) {
            jsonData = jsonData[curNode];
        }

        if (Array.isArray(jsonData)) {
            jsonData.some(function(thisData) {
                result = findValue(thisData, pathArr, targetField);
                return !!result; // Stops the `some` loop, doesn't exit `findValue`
            });
        } else {
            result = findValue(jsonData, pathArr, targetField);
        }
    }

    return result;
}
```

---

Note: I didn't do a full review of the code, just looked at return values.

Comment: thanks, I am trying to make the function entirely self-contained. Using a global variable to contain the return value is not a good idea at all.

Comment: Should use Array.find() instead of the closure retVal function - see my solution

Comment: @unobf: `Array#find` is neither better nor worse (except for requiring a polyfill) than using `some`.

Comment: @TonyGW: I see in another comment you have to support IE8. Note that `Array#some` (used above) will require a polyfill on such an old browser (it's from ES5, finalized in 2009), whereas anything modern will have `Array#some` (but may not have `Array#find` yet, as that's new in ES6, which hasn't been finalized yet).

Answer (score 1):

Here is the solution with some test data

```
function findValue(jsonData, pathArr, targetField) {
    var result = null;

    if (pathArr.length == 0 && jsonData.hasOwnProperty(targetField)) {
        result = targetField in jsonData ? jsonData[targetField] : result;
        return { value : result};
    } else {
        jsonData = jsonData[pathArr.shift()]
        if (Array.isArray(jsonData)) {
            jsonData.forEach(function(thisData) {
                result = findValue(thisData, pathArr, targetField);
            });
        } else if (typeof jsonData !== 'undefined') {
            return findValue(jsonData, pathArr, targetField);
        }
    }   
    return result;
}

testData = [{
    hello : 'hello',
    pathArr: []
}, {
    child : {
        hello : false
    },
    pathArr: ['child']
}, {
    child : {
        hello : null
    },
    pathArr: ['child']
}, {
    child: {
        child: {
            hell: 'hell'
        }
    },
    pathArr: ['child', 'child']
}];



testData.forEach(function (json) {
    console.log(findValue(json, json.pathArr, 'hello'));
});
```

Comment: Note: `Array#find` is an ES6 feature not present in many current browsers. You'll need a polyfill if you rely on it.

Comment: The question did not indicate whether a browser-only solution is required. This will work in modern browsers and Node.js

Comment: The assumption for browsers is IE 8 or older, chrome, and firefox, with IE being the majority.

Comment: Updated the solution to do two more things: work in browsers and also be able to return a value if the value of the json attribute is "null"

Comment: thanks, let me do some testing and I'll come back and report :)

Comment: @TonyGW The limitation with the solution the way it is working right now is that it will return the last match from an array. If there are multiple matches, the others will not match